# Flutter Riverpod - Functions called multiple times

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I created a flutter project that is connected with Socket.io Im facing a problem with riverpod in the homepage I used a consumerWidget and use Socket.on in the same widget to get the data from the api and update the UI.
My problem is when the API emits the clients gets multiple emits.
when I checked the API its emit once, so the problem in the flutter side.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef ref) {

    final StudentsArray Students = ref.read(StudentProvider as ProviderListenable<StudentsArray>);

    socket!.on("STD1",(std){
      Student temp = Student(std['pid'],std['name'], std['id'], std['Nationality'], std['birthdate'], std['age'], std['location'], std['pnumber'], std['snumber'], std['image'], std['level'], std['registertime'], std['rname'], std['class'],[],[],[],[],[]);
      ref.read(StudentProvider.notifier).addSTD(temp, '1');
    });


...
```

To get the emits once not multiple times

Answer (score 0):

First of all, subscribing/listening to anything inside the widget's `build` method is a bad idea in itself, because that method must not contain any side effects. Usually, you should create a subscription in the `initState` lifecycle and cancel it in the `dispose` lifecycle. In that case, you would want to extend the `ConsumerStatefulWidget` class instead.

Also, the provider you are trying to read doesn't look good. AFAIK, it should be just a `final` variable pointing to a valid provider. Anyway, the better approach would be to wrap the `socket` in its own provider which would then interact with the `StudentProvider` directly using `ref.watch(<Provider>)`.